# Unwanted JSON caching in Heroku app (node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, caching, heroku

I have a Node.js app running in a Heroku container and I'm experiencing some problems with writing and reading JSON files.

Here's how I'm reading and parsing JSON files:

```
const feedData = fs.readFileSync('./local/feed.json');
const parsedFeedData = JSON.parse(feedData);
```

For example, in one use case the parsed object gets passed to a function, to be updated and rewritten to JSON:

```
const updateFeed = (feed, index) => {
    const feedCopy = Object.assign([], feed);
    feedCopy.splice(index, 1);

    const json = JSON.stringify(feedCopy);
    fs.writeFileSync('./local/feed.json', json);
};
```

Running these operations locally, I don't encounter any problems but when being ran on Heroku, it acts as if I'm reading the JSON with `var parseJSON = require('./file-name');` and reads the data from the cache. I can tell this because the first data update (the function above) is always successful with reading and writing however the second time that function is ran, it reads a JSON file as if the first update never happened to that same JSON file.

I might be absolutely wrong but I suspect this might be due to caching that Heroku is doing. Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this with their node.js instances on Heroku?

Additional information *(still trying to find the culprit)* : The JSON file which is being read/written is initially uploaded with the git repo, so over time with mutation the JSON file will be different than the repo which is pushed over to Heroku. Is it possible that Heroku is trying to sync with the repo thus overriding the changes my code is making?